# Somar todas as colunas de uma matriz usando o numpy. Alguma forma melhor de fazer?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Eu fiz assim:

```
import numpy as np

#soma de todas as colunas de mat!

mat = np.arange(1,26).reshape(5,5)
print(mat)

lista =[]
for i in np.arange(0,len(mat)):
    lista.append(np.sum(mat[0:,i:i+1]))

print(np.array(lista))
```

A saída está correta:

```
[55 60 65 70 75]
```

Existe alguma forma melhor de fazer usando alguma função do numpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode calcular a soma das colunas diretamente com a função *sum*, informando o parâmetro: eixo 0 ('[axis=0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/glossary.html)'):

```
In [20]: mat.sum(axis=0)
Out[20]: array([55, 60, 65, 70, 75])
```

Documentação: [sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html)

Comment: não entendi bem o parâmetro axis. Poderia, por favor, explicar?

Comment: O parâmetro *axis* indica sobre qual eixo (em uma matriz 2d) a operação será feita. `axis=0` indica que a soma será feita em todas as linhas de cada coluna ("vertical"). `axis=1` indica que a soma será feita em todas as colunas de cada linha ("horizontal").